# How to create a nested dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a nested json as a target

```
[{'id':0, name:'Albert', last_name:'Einstein', info:{'dob':1903}},
 ...
 'id':100000, name:'Zooey', last_name:'Deschanel;', info:{'dob':1980}}
]
```

I am operating with an existing json converted into a dataframe, how can I form a valid nested dataframe and convert it back to json?

```
[{'id':0, name:'Albert', last_name:'Einstein', 'dob':1903, 'extra':{'field1': 1}},
...
{'id':100000, name:'Zooey', last_name:'Deschanel', 'dob':1980, 'extra':{'field1': 1}}

]
```

the following approach didn't really work

```
f.insert(2, 'info.dob', df['dob'])
df.drop(['dob'])
```

`{'id':0, name:'Albert', last_name:'Einstein', 'info.dob':1903}`

Comment: What would be a *nested dataframe*?

Comment: So, can you update a sample of your dataframe, please?

Comment: maybe I don't need a nested dataframe. What I am trying to achieve is a nested json in the end

Comment: Do you want the "extra" data? Or just id, name, last_name and dob?

Comment: we can drop the extra and just have id, name, last_name and dob nested in info

Comment: sorry, really need to use pandas. The file might contain M of objects.

Comment: @bekon - The `json` solution works regardless of the size of your json object/file. But I changed it to a `pandas` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.json_normalize` and then `apply` a custom function on column "dob":

```
import json
import pandas as pd

#assuming your json is stored in a file called "myjson.json"
df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(open("myjson.json").read()))
df["dob"] = df["dob"].apply(lambda x: {"info": x})

json_string = df.to_json(orient="records")
>>> json_string
'[{"id":0,"name":"Albert","last_name":"Einstein","dob":{"info":1903},"extra.field1":1},{"id":100000,"name":"Zooey","last_name":"Deschanel","dob":{"info":1980},"extra.field1":1}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Here is an example as Series:

```
series = pd.Series({'id':0,
                    'name':'Albert',
                    'last_name':'Einstein',
                    'info':{'dob':1903}
                   })
series
```

output:

```
id                       0
name                Albert
last_name         Einstein
info         {'dob': 1903}
dtype: object
```

back to json:

```
series.to_json()
```

output:

```
'{"id":0,"name":"Albert","last_name":"Einstein","info":{"dob":1903}}'
```

##### As DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id':0,
                    'name':'Albert',
                    'last_name':'Einstein',
                    'info':{'dob':1903}
                  
                  }])
```

output:

```
   id    name last_name           info
0   0  Albert  Einstein  {'dob': 1903}
```

Comment: how will it work in case of a full flow, I am reading json as df then convert them to series then add additional column and then convert back to json?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, complete novice here. I already have nested structure in my json, therefore read_json gives me an error, hence I am using json_normalize Secondly, I still need to use pandas as my file contains 100k lines. Lastly I need to convert each line to a correct format, the  dob is provided I just need to make it info:{'dob':xxx} for each object in my file

Comment: can you provide the expected output after adding your column?

Comment: I've tried this df.insert(2, 'info.dob', df['dob']) but the resulting json field is info.dob instead of a nested structure

Comment: so, in your example, you unnest `info`?